# How do I download many PubMed records using the easyPubMed package?

Tags: r, xml, r-package

Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. Currently running version 4.1.3 of R, tried re-installing the easyPubMed package, but nothing seems to work. Here's the code I have so far:

```
new_query <- "(APE1[TI] OR OGG1[TI]) AND (2012[PDAT]:2016[PDAT])"
out.A <- batch_pubmed_download(pubmed_query_string = new_query,dest_file_prefix = "easyPM_example", batch_size = 150, encoding = "UTF-8")
cat(readLines(out.A[1])[1:32], sep = "\n")
```

For some reason, it returns with 1 row of all the collected xml-style text, followed by 31 lines of NA.

I've also looked into using `fetching_pubmed_data()` to serve a similar purpose, but whenever I check the class of what I have, I get character, when it should be XMLInternalDocument and XMLAbstractDocument. Here's my code:

```
my_query <- '"genetic therapy"[MeSH Terms]'
my_entrez_id <- get_pubmed_ids(my_query)
my_abstracts_xml <- fetch_pubmed_data(my_entrez_id)
class(my_abstracts_xml)
```

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `readLines` call; both `batch_pubmed_download` and `fetch_pubmed_data`  work as expected.

In your `batch_pubmed_download` example, the downloaded files are XML files with three text lines (can confirm with `readLines` or in a terminal with `wc -l`). So `readLines(out.A[1])[1:32]` makes no sense, as only 3 lines exist and all the other indices lead to `NA`s. The XML content is in the first 3 lines.